# Finding volume of solid revolution about x-axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I'm asked to find the volume of a container of height $13.5$ The container is made by rotating $y = 1.5x^2$ where $0\leq x \leq 3$  about the axis $x=-0.5$ (the bottom is flat).

I tried finding the right volume a number of ways, but I believe my most solid attempt so far is this:

I invert the function to get $y = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}x}$.

From this I tried to calculate $\pi * \int_{0}^{3} \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}x} dx$ which gave me $3\pi$ which I thought was correct, but it wasnt. Plotting this, I realized the height becomes 3 when I integrate the inverted function from 0 to 3, so I thought I should maybe integrate from 0 to 13.5. In that case I get $\frac{243\pi}{4}$ which is also incorrect. I'm sure I've misinterpreted what it means to rotate the function about the axis $x=-0.5$... Any help is greatly appreaciated!

Comment: $x=-0.5$ is a line parallel to $y$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I translated $0.5$ units to the right so I had the equation

$$y=\frac{3}{2} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$
to rotate around $y$ axis and I got 
$$V=\pi  \int_0^3 \left(\frac{3}{2} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)^2 \, dx=\frac{14067 \pi }{320}\approx 138.1$$
Hope this is useful

Comment: shouldn't it be $x+1/2$?

Comment: @Vasya if you do $x+1/2$ you move to the left

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you did, but my maple TA is still giving me wrong on that answer

Comment: @novo: I think the problem is that when rotation is around $x=-0.5$ there is an additional cylinder from -1 to 0. Try to add $13.5\pi$ to the above answer.

Comment: I tried $(18387\pi)/320$ with no luck. I'm guessing it's more likely that my maple TA is bugged at this point. Not a task that's going to be handed in, but still slightly annoying to get it wrong when the method makes perfect sense. I thank you for your comment(s) though- atleast I'm aware of my initial mistake and the answer above seems perfectly logical for me.